# Alternatives to ordinal regression when proportional odds assumption is not met

Tags: r, regression, logistic, ordered-logit, link-function

I'm trying to fit an ordinal logistic regression using the ordinal package but the proportional odds assumption is not met. I have read all post here on this.

My specific question is that, if you change logit to probit link function, is the proportional odds assumption to be met?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which model should I use for ordinal data if one or some variables violate equal slopes?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/445610/which-model-should-i-use-for-ordinal-data-if-one-or-some-variables-violate-equal)