# Which model should I use for ordinal data if one or some variables violate equal slopes?

Tags: r, regression, ordered-logit

I have running the data for an experiment. There are 3 independent variables in my data namely "Rhyme", "Meter"
and "Lexicality" all with 2 levels (0/1) respectively. Based on these parameters the beauty of sentences will be rated on a five-point scale. There are many functions on R to run ordinal data and I have tried the polr(), clm() and vglm(), but what bothers me is the variable "Lexicality" violates proportional odds assumptions but the other two variables hold. I have tried the parallel line test, likelihood test etc and they all showed that one variable definitely violated the proportional odds assumption.

What should I do in this case? Which model should I use for my data?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest alternative is probably multinomial logistic regression, which ignores the ordinality of the dependent variable but also avoids the assumption of proportional odds.

Another possibility is partial proportional odds.

Comment: Hello Mr. Flom, thank you very much for your advice. The multinomial logistic regression would be an option for and I found many examples on the Internet. However, I found less information about partial proportional odds. Could you please tell me with which function or package on R I can run the partial proportional odds model? Thank you very much!

Comment: The ordinal package does it.